# Не удаётся запустить Ruby 1.8.7 и Rails 2 на Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, ruby-on-rails

```
C:\mmm>rake db:schema:load
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake: No such file or directory - gcc -shared -s  -g -O2 -DFD_SET
SIZE=256    -I C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby187/include "C:/Us
ers/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065db
e0df70a.c" -lfreeimage -lfreeimage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby1
87/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18 -o "C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageS
cience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.so" -L.
rake aborted!
error executing "gcc -shared -s  -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256    -I C:/Ruby187/lib/ru
by/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby187/include \"C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-
1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c\" -lfreeimage -lfreei
mage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby187/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18 -o \"C:
/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d5006
5dbe0df70a.so\" -L.  ":
Renamed C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be158
3cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c to C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageSc
ience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c.bad
C:/mmm/config/environment.rb:8
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Играюсь с RoR, а мне вот такое пишут. Что это вообще, как убить багу? Гугл по этому вопрос совсем ничего не дал.

И вот что показывает --trace

```
C:\mmm>rake db:schema:load --trace
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake: No such file or directory - gcc -shared -s  -g -O2 -DFD_SET
SIZE=256    -I C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby187/include "C:/Us
ers/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065db
e0df70a.c" -lfreeimage -lfreeimage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby1
87/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18 -o "C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageS
cience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.so" -L.
rake aborted!
error executing "gcc -shared -s  -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256    -I C:/Ruby187/lib/ru
by/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby187/include \"C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-
1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c\" -lfreeimage -lfreei
mage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby187/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18 -o \"C:
/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d5006
5dbe0df70a.so\" -L.  ":
Renamed C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageScience_cdabbf6be158
3cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c to C:/Users/Pozitron/.ruby_inline/ruby-1.8/Inline_ImageSc
ience_cdabbf6be1583cf10d50065dbe0df70a.c.bad
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/RubyInline-3.12.1/lib/inline.rb:610:in `build'

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/RubyInline-3.12.1/lib/inline.rb:848:in `inline
'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/image_science-1.2.4/lib/image_science.rb:87
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:61:in
`load'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:250:in `load_ge
ms'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:250:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:250:in `load_ge
ms'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process
'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:97:in `send'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/initializer.rb:97:in `run'
C:/mmm/config/environment.rb:8
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original
_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/depende
ncies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/misc.rake:3
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `invoke_wi
th_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_wi
th_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `invoke_pr
erequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_pr
erequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke_wi
th_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_wi
th_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `in
voke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `to
p_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `ea
ch'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `to
p_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `ru
n_with_threads'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top
_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run
'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `st
andard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run
'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в свой вопрос, что вам показывает команда __gcc -v__?

Comment: "gcc" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

кажется, у меня что-то не установлено?

Comment: Ну да, вы же видите, что _No such file or directory - gcc..._. К сожалению, у меня нет под рукой Windows, поэтому не могу вам точно посоветовать, что нужно делать для настройки ruby-окружения. В любом случае удивляет, что у вас достаточно старая версия Ruby и совсем-совсем старая версия Rails.

Comment: а заставить всё это счастье работать под теми версиями, что есть — нереально?

Comment: Наверняка, заставить-то можно. Вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Очень хочется, чтобы всё заработало. На текущих сборках.

А к какому пакету, gem'у принадлежит команда "gcc" под виндами? Что необходимо установить?

Comment: _А к какому пакету, gem'у принадлежит команда "gcc" под виндами? Что необходимо установить?_

Советую, внимательно погуглить не gcc, а "Windows and RubyInline".

Answer (score 1):

```
Очень хочется, чтобы всё заработало. На текущих сборках.
```

Тогда бейтесь. Вам нужно:

1. Отредактировать название своего вопроса, сделать его значительно более подробно сформулированным, что-то вроде: "Не удаётся запустить `Ruby 1.8.7` и `Rails 2` на `Windows`", чтобы не путать общим вопросом аудиторию.
2. Скорее всего (85%) проблема с `image_science` (это `gem` для обработки изображений), который использует `RubyInline`, который плохо дружит с `Windows` - нужно погуглить их обоих на совместимость с `Windows`. Если выяснится, что проблема в `image_science` - добавить `Image Science` в формулировку своего вопроса.
3. Разобраться, почему `image_science & RubyInline` пытаются запустить `gcc` и, если это добро, выяснить, почему его нет у вас на `windows`.

Вот, это для начала.

Comment: принято, спасибо.
буду шаманить.

Comment: Если вы в состоянии это сделать, попробуйте вот этот альтернативный вариант https://github.com/asynchrony/image_science, который не требует RubyInline (https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/431#issuecomment-863571)

Comment: Чтобы попробовать эту альтернативную версию image_science, выполните где-нибудь в любой временной директории:    
       
    gem uninstall image_science
    git clone https://github.com/asynchrony/image_science
    cd image_science
    gem build image_science.gemspec
    gem install image_science-1.3.2.1.Asynchrony.gem

Эти команды удаляют с вашей системы официальный image_science, берут альтернативный вариант и вручную создают и устанавливают из него gem. Сообщите о том, как у вас это получилось/не получилось на Windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production
```

если вы хотите проект запустить в продакшен

но лучше конечно использовать миграции

Comment: увы, оно не сработало.

Comment: Думал всё намного проще и проглядел что вы под виндами. 

Заинстальте ДевКит штоле http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/